# Using a 2D array as an index to a 3D array

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array, slice

I have a three-dimensional array in R, e.g.

```
a <- array(1:24, dim=c(2,3,4))
```

I'll refer to the dimensions of this array as rows, columns and layers. 
I have a second variable, **b**, which is intended to provide an index to that array, e.g.

```
b <- array(c(1,4,3,2,2,1), dim=c(2,3))
```

I would like to get a two-dimensional variable, **d** that contains the value from 3D variable **a** in the layer specified by **b** for each row and column in **a** and **b**. So for example, `d[1, 1] <- a[1, 1 , b[1, 1]]` and `d[2, 3] <- a[2, 3, b[2, 3]]` and so on. In this example, I should end up with:

```
 d == array(c(1, 20, 15, 10, 11, 6), dim=c(2, 3))
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way you can do this:

```
structure(a[cbind(c(row(b)),c(col(b)),c(b))],.Dim=dim(b))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   15   11
[2,]   20   10    6
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `expand.grid` to get all combinations of rows and columns in `b` and then use `mapply` to get the corresponding output from `a` using indexing. We use `relist` to make the `d` matrix same as `b`.

```
df <- expand.grid(row = 1:nrow(b), col = 1:ncol(b))
d <- relist(mapply(function(x, y) a[x, y, b[x, y]], df$row, df$col), b)
d

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1   15   11
#[2,]   20   10    6
```

where `df` is

```
   row col
#1   1   1
#2   2   1
#3   1   2
#4   2   2
#5   1   3
#6   2   3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `expand.grid` as well, but I would generate an index matrix to adress every entry of `a` at once.

```
ind <- as.matrix(expand.grid(1:nrow(b), 1:ncol(b)))
d <- matrix(a[cbind(ind, b[ind])], ncol = ncol(b), nrow = nrow(b))
```

I think this is **slightly** more efficient